# VBScript + Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, vbscript

```
Dim sString

sString = "John;Mary;Anne;Adam;Bill;Ester"
```

Is there a regex I can use to retrieve the following from the above list:

1. John (; at the end of the name)
2. Anne (; at the beginning and end)
3. Ester (; at the beginning)

I am currently using the following regex for each:

```
1. Joh.*
2. .*An.*
3. .*st.*
```

But, the above retrieves the entire string instead of the values I want. How can I get the correct values?

Code:

```
Dim oRegex : Set oRegex = New RegExp
oRegex.Global = False
oRegex.IgnoreCase = False

'John
oRegex.Pattern = "Joh.*"

Set oMatch = oRegex.Execute(sString)
sName = oMatch(0)
```

The above code retrieves the entire string, instead of only John. Same issue with the others :(

Comment: Is there a reason not to use, for example, oRegex.Pattern = "John;"?  That is, if you know the exact names you want out, why not just use them as the pattern?  Also, ".*" matches everything, that's why you're getting the full string.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use this?

```
Dim nameArray = Split(sString,";")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Eric.

I'm not sure it because the string is HUGE and using Split causes a big performance overhead..

Comment: Not as much as the overhead from a regex.

Answer (score 1):

easier way, do a `split()` on your string. Then iterate the list to get your stuff eg

```
s = split(sString,";")
for i=Lbound(s) to Ubound(s)
  ' get your names
next
```

Comment: Thanks ghostdog74. I'm not sure it because the string is HUGE and using Split causes a big performance overhead.